# Will I have problems getting off a US-Europe cruise at a port and not returning, assuming I've gotten a visa?

Tags: cruising

If I take a cruise from Florida to Spain just for example, and I already have a visa for Spain, is there any likely negative consequence of just staying in Spain (or going to the airport and flying to a nearby country, also with a visa)?

I'd like to go to Turkey and am considering taking a cheap US-Europe cruise, getting off at a convenient port, and flying the short distance to Turkey.

Comment: Remember there's more to leaving the ship than walking down the gangway. You'll have at least some luggage to carry, and you'll have to check out of the ship's hotel services to settle the bar and restaurant bill, to tip, and to let them know you're leaving voluntarily and haven't fallen (or been thrown) over the rail and gone into the ocean.

Comment: Also, "just staying" implies that you intend to stay unlawfully, or past what your visa may allow. That won't go down well with the law of either the country you choose to stay in, or the country you're a resident of.

Comment: What is the actual itinerary of the cruise? If it actually just goes from Florida to Spain, not only can you get off the ship in Spain, you actually _have to_... Transatlantic cruises are often sold one-way, so you would be in that situation.

Comment: Contact cruise line. They offer (for a fee) the possibility to disembark on other ports. But usually cruise line have your passport, so you cannot just walk off. And cruise ship is in a special status, so you will possibly not pass immigration (so such things should be prepared in advance). In any case transatlantic cruise ships will terminate in good connected ports (and probably more convenient to go in Turkey). And there are TA cruises which terminates in Spain. Note: technically they are not "cruises" but "repositioning" (but so very cheap)